# How to avoid MySQL + Django TimeField shooting itself in the foot at midnight?

Tags: python, mysql, django, time, django-models

MySQL 5.7.22 (but this happened with earlier versions) too. Happened with Django 1.8, now with Django 1.11, so wide range of MySQL and Django versions.

```
class ShootFootAtMidnight(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_source = models.ForeignKey(TimeSource)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.time_source:
            self.time = self.time_source.time
        super(ShootFootAtMidnight, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, if there are a ton of these created around midnight time, sooner or later I'll face this:

`ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`

Beware, because this is not a conventional `models.DateTimeField` but it's only the `time` part of that. This error never happened with me with `DateTimeFields` although the object has such (`auto_now`) as well. The `models.TimeField` has the type `time` in the MySQL DB (whereas `DateTimeField` has `datetime` and `DateField` has `date`.

If I look at the database with MySQL prompt, I see the object is created honky and dory and has a time of `24:00:00`. This value did not come from an `auto_now` field. Django actually created an object what it cannot read back (?!?!?). If I manually correct the time to `23:59:59` the `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23` goes away, but how can I prevent this from happening?

---

This is just my suspicion: is this a rounding issue on MySQL side? Maybe the Django framework supplies something like 23:59:59:99934. And if the `time` DB type's resolution is just 3 milliseconds, then it'll round it up to 24:00:00 without `Django` knowing it. But I was not able to prove that yet, I cannot find the exact resolution of the `time` but I feel it cannot be 6 fractional digits what Django displays sometimes. If this is the case I should maybe manually `self.time = self.time_source.time.replace(microsecond=0)` or something?

Comment: Where are you getting the TimeSource from?  I see it's a foreign key and it looks like you're verifying it exists before you stick it into the database, but it looks like it could be being created in the foreign location incorrectly before anything else.  All the while, I don't see why you're not simply adjusting the time at the assignment "self.time = self.time_source.time".

Comment: That's also a Django model. Either it is an `auto_now` field, or gets a value deducted from a `datetime` call, for the sake of symmetry: if Django let's me to set it, how is it not able to read it out then?

Comment: I can assure you that there's no manual manipulation of the data. Whatever I get form the system is assigned to that variable. It's basically a time stamp

Comment: My suspicion is that this is a rounding issue on MySQL side. Probably the Django framework supplies something like `23:59:59:99934`. And if the `TIME` type's resolution is just 3 milliseconds, then it'll round it up to `24:00:00` without Django knowing it. But I was not able to prove that yet, I cannot find the `TIME` resolution. If this is the case I should maybe manually `self.time = self.time_source.time.microseconds(0)` or something?

Comment: Can you add the "describe table" to the question so we can be sure the field format is what we're expecting?  For example, I receive an "Incorrect datetime value" if I attempt to insert a 24:00:00 time into a datetime(6), so I'm curious of how that value is being inserted into the db.

Comment: @Gerik `models.TimeField` has a type of `time` in the MySQL DB. It's nullable.

Comment: @Gerik `models.DateTime` field has a MySQL type `datetime` and `models.DateField` has a type `date`. Interestingly, this type of error never happened to me with a `datetime` field, although I have `created` and `last_modified` timestamps as well, the one in this error is a 3rd time stamp, and only the time part of it. Historically the date and time is split into a separate date and a time field.

Comment: Hey Csaba, from what I can tell it appears what's happening is that the TIME field has the ability to hold 24:xx:xx clock values (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html), however, this is being referenced/used in a the datetime field which does not allow 24 hour clock values.  You need to sanitize the time field before you use it with the datetime value.

Comment: @Gerik I guess so, but it's still weird that the Django framework allows something to be written what I cannot read back.